# why all the listItem components are not polpulating

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

*** i map through an array and for every item m calling ListItem component so there should be 3 ListItems but only one is getting populated ,dont know what wrong please help

*** this my app js ***

```
import FeedbackList from "./components/FeedbackList";
import FeedbackStatus from "./components/FeedbackStatus";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import feedbackData from "./data/feedback";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header/>
     <FeedbackStatus feedback={feedbackData}/>
     <FeedbackList/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*** this is my feedbacklist component , where i map through feedbackData and for each item i m calling feedbackItem component , passed item as prop ***

```
import React from "react";
import FeedbackItem from "./FeedbackItem";
import { useState } from "react";
import feedbackData from "../data/feedback";

function FeedbackList() {
  const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState(feedbackData);

  return (
    <div className="feedbackList">
      <div className="imgcon">
        <img
          className="feedbackimage"
          src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220930/original/pngtree-customer-reviews-with-people-giving-star-ratings-on-a-mobile-phone-png-image_8644419.png"
          alt="feedback"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="showfeedback">
        {feedback.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeedbackList;
```

*** my  feedbackData ***
const feedbackData =  [

```
    {
        id: 1,
        rating: 10,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. consequuntur vel vitae commodi alias voluptatem est voluptatum ipsa quae.',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        rating: 9,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. consequuntur vel vitae commodi alias voluptatem est voluptatum ipsa quae.',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        rating: 8,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. consequuntur vel vitae commodi alias voluptatem est voluptatum ipsa quae.',
      },
    ]
    


export default feedbackData
```

*** this is my feedbackItem component , here i have received item as prop ***

import React from 'react'

```
function FeedbackItem({item}) {
  return (
    <div className='feedbackItem'>
      <p className='rating'> {item.rating}</p>
      <p className='review'></p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FeedbackItem
```

*** this is my css if it helps ***

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(9, 154, 154);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.heading{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;

}

.feedbackList{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
.imgcon{
  flex: 4;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.showfeedback{
flex: 6;
}
.feedbackimage{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.feedbackItem{
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: aquamarine;
width: 50vw;
height: 20vh;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 110px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.review{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px ;
  color:#fff;

}
.rating{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(251, 221, 51);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: black;
}
.states{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.states :nth-child(1){
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.states :nth-child(2){
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Because position of all your feedback item is set to absolute, so i believe they are getting hidden behind each other and you're seeing only one

Comment: You can check @CodeManiac's theory by opening the *Elements* tab within Dev Tools

Comment: thanks @CodeManiac  bro i checked in react development tool and in inspect section ,it was showing 3 components thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0):

```
    import FeedbackList from "./components/FeedbackList";
    import FeedbackStatus from "./components/FeedbackStatus";
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import feedbackData from "./data/feedback";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
         <Header/>
         <FeedbackStatus feedback={feedbackData}/>
         <FeedbackList feedbackData={feedbackData}/> 
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;


function FeedbackList(props) {
  const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState(props.feedbackData);

  return (
    <div className="feedbackList">
      <div className="imgcon">
        <img
          className="feedbackimage"
          src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220930/original/pngtree-customer-reviews-with-people-giving-star-ratings-on-a-mobile-phone-png-image_8644419.png"
          alt="feedback"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="showfeedback">
        {feedback.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @krishna, FeedbackList(props) not passing the props, after passing the props from both side means 1st <FeedbackList feedbackData={feedbackData}/>, 2nd useState(props.feedbackData);